# Hash Not Defined for Class Reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have a funny error occuring where I have a custom class I am using as keys in a `std::unordered_map`. I have implemented a hash function for this custom class.

If I create an `std::unordered_map` like so everything runs fine:

```
std::unordered_map <Component, int> myMap;
```

But if I create a `std::unordered_map` where the keys are references it complains there is no implemented hash function for this type:

```
std::unordered_map <Component&, int> myMap;
```

> Error 3   error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

```
class Component
{
public:
    GUID id;

    Component()
    { 
        generateGUID(&id);
    }

    bool operator== (const Component& other) const
    {
        return compareGUID(id, other.id);
    }
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<Component>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Component& cmp) const
        {
            using std::size_t;
            using std::hash;

            return hash<GUID>()(cmp.id); // GUID hash has also been implemented
        }
    };
}


std::unordered_map<Component, int> cMap1;  // compiles ok
std::unordered_map<Component&, int> cMap2;  // causes compiler error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not how to correctly override hash for `Component&`. The problem is that STL containers are meant to store objects and references are not objects. Mind that the term *object* includes primitives and pointers, since they require storage, while a reference does not.

To overcome your problem you should look into [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), which is able to wrap a reference inside an object, then the code would become something [like](http://ideone.com/ZrOege):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct Component
{
    size_t id;
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<reference_wrapper<Component>>
    {
        size_t operator()(const reference_wrapper<Component>& cmp) const
        {
            return cmp.get().id;
        }
    };
}

unordered_map<reference_wrapper<Component>, int> mapping;
```

If you don't want to use reference_wrapper then you should use pointers (`Component*`) as keys.